# Create Android project in my local git repository

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I have a git repository cloned from github. Then I go to my local copy of that repository. There are sub-module projects in the repository.

Now, I would like to create a new Android project. So, in Eclipse I did:

**File -> New Android Application Project -> (fill project name, etc) Next -> I browse to my git repository**, but Eclipse **doesn't allow** me to create project there, it complains "**Folder is not empty**".

But I need my new Android project to be created in the repository. How to get rid of this problem with eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your android project in an empty folder and then copy and paste the contents into the root of the directory where you have a git project.

You'll need to make sure you add everything with `git add -A`